# Rails simple search Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

My table User looks like this

```
Name      |   SecondName
-------------------------
"David"   |  "Graham"
-------------------------
"Gary"    | "Jules"
-------------------------
"Gary"    | "Lincon"
```

Im trying with this function in my model

```
def nameSearch(search)
 where('name like ? OR secondName like ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
end
```

My function works with these:

`User.nameSearch("Gary")` returns 2 record

`User.nameSearch ("ary")` returns 2 record

How can I make this search work?

```
User.nameSearch("Gary Jules") returns nil
```

It should return 2 records instead of nil.

Comment: Tokenize search variable into two tokens.

Comment: @trueinViso I could define a function that accepts two parameters but it will only return the exact search (1 record). Instead I want to return all the records. In my example the result I´m searching for would return 2 records.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string on the space to get an array, add the % wildcards then query with this array, something like:

```
def name_search(search)
    search_terms = search.split(" ")
    search_terms_with_wildcard = search_terms.map {|val| "%#{val}%" }
    Product.where("name LIKE ANY ( array[?] ) OR secondName LIKE ANY ( array[?] )", search_terms_with_wildcard, search_terms_with_wildcard)
end
```

Comment: Hello, thats a great suggestion, but it is throwing me an error :

`SQLite3::SQLException: near "['%Gary%','%Jules%']"`

Perhaps slqlite3 is the problem. Should I use postgresql?

Comment: For some reason my brain wasn't thinking in sqlite3 for the question.  My bad.   I'll rewrite this after work for you, in active record if I can be bothered.  Check back later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would return the exact search if you tried a 2 parameter method, it should really solve your problem.

```
def name_search(first, last)
  where("name like ? OR second_name like ?", "%#{first}%", "%#{last}%")
end
```

By the way, make your `method name` into snake case, that's the convention for rails.